# ContainerDiv that self-adjusts width to random number of images loaded inside breaks apart when i insert it inside another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

It has been two days im trying to solve this and i cant.

I made a customized div that displays images in a kind of a bar that auto-adjusts itself and stays centered.

And i made it work here:

https://codepen.io/SCalmStorm/pen/povwaed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">


<head>
<style>
.imgstyle{
        display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  background-position: 50px 50px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;

}
#containerItem{
    margin: auto;
    Position: relative;
    top: 65px;
    background: green;

    min-width: 10px;
    max-width: 700px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
    z-index: 21;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
body {
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: khaki;

    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 

}
</style>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<!--    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quantico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Quiz App</title>

   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> -->
</head>
<div class="bg"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
              crossorigin="anonymous">        
 </script>


<body>
<div id="containerItem">
</div>


</body>

 <script> 
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1  
    alert(number)
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
var img = document.createElement('img')
    document.getElementById('containerItem').appendChild(img);


        img.src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/54/a2/c6/54a2c62234d05c174e344b235cbb6f49.jpg";
        img.className = "imgstyle";
}

var newDiv = document.createElement('img')
newDiv.id = "containerItem"




 </script>

</html>
```

And that is great. But as i worked on my other script i needed it inserted in another div with the class StandardSlide. But it completely breaks apart :(. And the only thing i understand is that it conflicts with the position:fixed. But when i turn it off, or change it to others it messes up my container. How can i solve this without messing it up? Or without changing the fixed? Why is the fix from this new container affecting the other divs :(, i know it has to do with the relative that inherits the parent style :(:

This one, it no longer adjusts the green bar to the images.

https://codepen.io/SCalmStorm/pen/xxbPqVw

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">


<head>
<style>
.imgstyle{
        display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  background-position: 50px 50px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;

}

.StandardSlide{
    Position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    background: rgba(75, 39, 73, 0.7);
    left: 15%;
    right: 15%;
    /*width: 80%;*/
    bottom: 5%;
    /*background-color: white;*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
    z-index: 20;
}

#containerItem{
    margin: auto;
    Position: relative;
    top: 65px;
    background: green;

    min-width: 10px;
    max-width: 700px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
    z-index: 21;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
body {
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: khaki;

    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 

}
</style>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<!--    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quantico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Quiz App</title>

   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> -->
</head>
<div class="bg"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
              crossorigin="anonymous">        
 </script>


<body>
<div class="StandardSlide">
  <div id="containerItem">
  </div>
</div>


</body>

 <script> 
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1  
    //alert(number)
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
var img = document.createElement('img')
    document.getElementById('containerItem').appendChild(img);


        img.src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/54/a2/c6/54a2c62234d05c174e344b235cbb6f49.jpg";
        img.className = "imgstyle";
}

var newDiv = document.createElement('img')
newDiv.id = "containerItem"




 </script>

</html>
```